# Script to Import data into SQL table from flat file (text file) .XYZ file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a script to import flat files into SQL Server tables. I tried using the import wizard but since I need to do this periodically I would have to create a SQL function in order to achieve this and I am not sure how to go about it. The flat files are stored in the following format:

```
19350.000    45978.000     1560.631
19352.000    45978.000     1560.234
19354.000    45978.000     1560.021
19356.000    45978.000     1559.809
19358.000    45978.000     1559.596
```

I have tried the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
 Id int identity (1,1),
  X float,
  Y float,
 Z float
 )


  BULK INSERT #TempTable FROM 
'\\fcgwnt01\share.$\StandardHaulage\TEST\Automated\EVO\SurfaceFiles\EVO 2019- 
01-23.xyz'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '**\t**', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')


SELECT * INTO [dbo].[SHM_EVO_SURFACE_DETAILS] FROM #TempTable

--Drop temporary table
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

But I'm getting the following errors

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
> The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
> The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 12
> Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)"

Comment: You could try using bulk insert - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Is SSIS an option for you?

Comment: No unfortunately SSIS isn't an option

Comment: I assume this is a tab delimited file? If so, why have you used FIELDTERMINATOR = '**\t**' rather than just FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t' ?

Comment: I meant 'asterix asterix\t asterix asterix' - seems Stackoverflow is treating asterixes as formatting code